# Setup a DNS server on a Pi for a private network consists of PCs, Pis and Android phones

Tags: dns

I want to setup a DNS server for machine lookup in a LAN. That is, after the computers receive an IP address from my router DHCP server, I want the computer names (assigned by the OS) to be usable as domain names in place of the assigned IP addresses.

Equipments:

- A router.
- A [Nano Pi M4](https://www.friendlyarm.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=234) as a DNS server.
- PC, other Pis and Android phones. I want the phones to get their own domain names be usable with ADB over IP, without using USB cables.

How do I setup my DNS server on the Pi? Currently, I have to assign fix IP addresses to the devices. I read that you can setup Bind for DNS server and after that, add this private DNS server to your router, is that correct?

Comment: "_Currently, I have to assign fix IP addresses to the devices._" Why not use DHCP reservations instead of statically assigning addresses on the devices?

Comment: Thanks. I will look that up.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I setup my DNS server on the Pi?

[Online tutorials such as this one for Raspberry Pi/BIND](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/configuration/how-to-make-your-raspberry-pi-into-a-dns-server/) may be of help with setting up a basic DNS server on your device.

> I read that you can setup BIND for a DNS server and after that, add this private DNS server to your router, is that correct?

Technically this depends on your router, but in most instances, yes. You essentially tell the router (via its configuration options) to send all of its DNS queries to your DNS server (Raspberry Pi) rather than to e.g. your ISP.

One thing to remember is that you must configure the DNS server to forward non-local traffic (anything outside your LAN e.g. `google.com`) to another DNS server (e.g. your ISP's). In the tutorial linked above, this is the `forwarders {}` section under `named.conf.options`. If you fail to set this up correctly, you won't be able to access the internet.

> After the computers receive an IP address from my router DHCP server, I want the computer names (assigned by the OS) to be usable as domain names in place of the assigned IP addresses.

It's a little unclear to me what you mean by "assigned by the OS". Name to IP address mapping is controlled by the DNS server software. For instance, a typical BIND entry might look like:

```
example.lan.  IN A  10.0.0.10  ; A Record for a basic domain name
```

Therefore, any entries for a device (IP address) need to be created in e.g. BIND ahead of using any domain name to reference that device (IP address). In practice, this means the DHCP address assigned to each device needs to remain (relatively) static and all of your domain name entries will need to appear in e.g. BIND before they can be accessed.

> I want the phones to get their own domain names and be usable with ADB over IP, without using USB cables.

You will need to create separate domains for each device (IP address) in your DNS server software. The other changes needed to connect to that device will likely need to be done in ADB, your router or possibly on the device itself.

> Currently, I have to assign fix IP addresses to the devices.

You don't need to do this with a DNS server but (as already mentioned) the IP address for each device does need to remain (relatively) static (as assigned by your DHCP server/router).